# Displaying No Records Found in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been searching and wondering if there is any directive to help display " No data found " in a table when the table is empty in angular 2. Or better still i can create that functionality in my services when i am subscribing to a fetched data ?

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let game of Games">

         </td>
          <td>{{game.name}}</td>
          <td>{{game.type}}</td>
          </tr>


      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The tag angularjs should only be used for Angular 1.x Please do not reject the edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check for the **`length`** of array if there are no elements uisng **`length`**, then display it as **`NO DATA`**,

```
<li  *ngIf="Games?.length == 0">
    <span class="search_no_results">
       No data found 
    </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the newest feature from **Angular 4.0.0** and to add `if else` statement:

```
<div *ngIf="Games?.length;else no_data_templ">
    <table>
        <tbody>
           <tr *ngFor="let game of Games">
                <td>{{game.name}}</td>
                <td>{{game.type}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<ng-template #no_data_templ>
     No daata found...
</ng-template>
```

**Update**: for Angular 2.X you can use the following approach:

```
<div *ngIf="Games?.length">
    <table>
        <tbody>
           <tr *ngFor="let game of Games">
                <td>{{game.name}}</td>
                <td>{{game.type}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div *ngIf="! Games?.length">
     No data found...
</div>
```

Comment: No, it will not work. For 2.3 you have to set two if conditions: `<div *ngIf="Games?.length;"> your content</div>` and `<div *ngIf="!Games?.length;">No data found</div>`. But I recomment you to update to Angular 4. The migrations is easy ;)

Comment: I will upgrade soon but sometimes it creates some errors that are hectic to fix sometimes.  Could you please make the conditions clearer by may be re-editing the answer as part of it?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display a message saying no data found. Before the table tag check whether Games has items to iterate.

Something like this

```
public hasData(): boolean {
 return (this.Games != null && this.Games.length > 0);
}
```

Use hasData() in the template

```
<div *ngIf="!hasData()">No Data Found</div>
<table *ngIf="hasData()">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let game of Games">

         </td>
          <td>{{game.name}}</td>
          <td>{{game.type}}</td>
          </tr>


      </tbody>
</table>
```

You can structure & style this in anyway you want.

Answer (score 0):

add these codes in your html file

```
<div class="card-body">
   <mat-table[dataSource]="listData" [hidden]="!isTableHasData">
   .......
   .......
   </mat-table>
   <div [hidden]="isTableHasData" style="text-align: center;">
   no records found..
   </div>
 </div>
```

this code is for .ts file

```
  isTableHasData = true;
      applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        this.listData.filter = this.searchKey.trim().toLowerCase();
        if(this.listData.filteredData.length > 0) {
          this.isTableHasData = true;
        } else {
          this.isTableHasData = false;
        }
      }
```

just use this code hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `*ngIf else`

```
<ng-template #no_data>
 No data found!!!
</ng-template >
<div *ngIf="Games.length > 0; else no_data">
<table>
    <tbody>
       <tr *ngFor="let game of Games">
            <td>{{game.name}}</td>
            <td>{{game.type}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```